# Repository to upgrade Sigil to latest version on (K)ubuntu

Tags: repository

I'd like to upgrade [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/) to the latest version (currently it is 0.7.2), and I'm looking for a repository that provides it.

The Sigil website [lists](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/wiki/LinuxDistroPackages) some repositories for various Linux distros, but the ubuntu one (the one I need) doesn't seems updated anymore; from there, I can only get version 0.6.2.

There are some other repositories beside this one?

EDIT: I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 Precise

Comment: That's funny, because if I go  to https://launchpad.net/~rgibert/+archive/ebook it seems to be even older than 0.6.3. Building from source, maybe using the git repository is, as for now, the only way to get the newest version.

Comment: Yes, it shows an older version, but I'm quite sure that I've installed it from there. Anyway, I'm not in extreme need, so I think I will wait, I've read that its QT5 dependencies are a mess for 12.04

Comment: I can try and build this in a separate PPA, using the old debian/ file to build the new code, no clue if it'll work or not, would that help?

Comment: Thank you but there is no need to do it, I was looking for a (semi)official one.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find an official one, short of downloading and building the source yourself.

Answer (score 0):

most safety way to upgrade your sigil package is from source code... because this package doesn't include on official repository in Ubuntu..